# how to invoke Out Of Office Service in lotus notes domino in Java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

i am using domino designer 8.5.3 and my notes client and server are also above version 8. Manager level access is given to the user and run on behalf of field is also set correctly. can anyone tell me how to start out of office service through java code.

Comment: What do you mean by start the service? When it is configured on the servier, the service is always running. Are you asking about how to turn on Out of Office notifications for the specific user? Also, have you seen these documents from IBM? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006404

Comment: yes..i want to turn on the out of office service through java code and i want to customize the Date and message through code..plz help..

Answer (score 1):

There is some sample code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126965/out-of-office-agent-lotus-domino) that shows how to access the Out Of Office profile document.

For the rest of it, I can't answer your question, but I can teach you how to answer your own question.

The fields in that document control the Out of Office settings. You want to change those settings in code, so you need to figure out exactly what changes occur in those fields when you manually do what you want your code to do for you.  You will need to analyze those fields to figure out which ones changed when you do it manually.  These are the fields you need to change in code.

You can use NotesPeek to look at the fields and their values.  Doing this before and after making manual changes to the settings, and compare the values of the fields should give you everything you need to know, but because of caching of profile document values, I would recommend the following steps:

1. Use NotesPeek to examine and record the field values in the Out of Office profile
2. Using the Notes client, manually make the changes to Out of Office settings exactly as you want your code to do.
3. Shut down Notes completely. (This means the client, designer, and admin clients, and NotesPeek. Everything. If you have any doubts, just reboot.)
4. Use NotesPeek to examine the field values in the Out of Office profile, comparing them to the values that you previously recorded. Note what has changed.

Then just write your Java code to modify the appropriate fields, and save the profile document.